# Regex match - Python - any amount of characters

Tags: python, regex, parsing, string-parsing

Cannot find an example that looks like what I am looking for.

I am trying to capture ASN numbers in an FAA Aeronautical NOTAM. Example Below:

**Example Text**:

```
2019-AWP-7268-OE
```

**Regex Match (findall)**:

```
\d{4}-(?:AAL|ACE|AEA|AGL|ANE|ANM|ASO|ASW|AWP|WTE|WTW)-(?:\d{3,6})-(?:OE|NRA)
```

However, I also want to capture it when multiple are issued:

- 2019-AWP-659 THRU 662-NRA
- 2019-AWP-3823/3825-NRA
- 2019-AWP-4593/4594/4595/4596-NRA
- 2019-ASW-4791, 4794 THRU 4796, 4798 THRU 4800-NRA

I get caught up trying to make an expression where any amount of characters but the expression ends in OE/NRA. Is there any way to match the Year (2019), Region (ASW|AWP), *Any Text (3823/3825)*, then Type (OE|NRA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
r'((\d{4})-(AAL|ACE|AEA|AGL|ANE|ANM|ASO|ASW|AWP|WTE|WTW)-([^-]+)-(OE|NRA))'
```

which, when given as a key to `re.findall()`, should produce a nested list, where the outer list contains each big match, and the inner list contains the four sub-matches within each match (as elements 1, 2, 3, and 4 of a tuple, respectively; element 0 is the full single pattern match).

Thereafter, you can do another iteration of regex operations, or some other operations, specifically on the *any text* portion of the match, to isolate exactly which IDs or whatever you're dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

To match *any text* you could also use `.*` which will match until the end of the line and will then backtrack to match the last occurrence of of `-` and will then match either `OE` or `NRA`

You could shorten the alternation a bit by adding some characters to a character class like `A[AG]L` to match either `AAL` or `AGL`

Note that you don't need the non capturing group around `(?:\d{3,6})`

```
^(\d{4})-(ACE|AEA|A[AG]L|AN[EM]|AS[WO]|AWP|WT[EW])-(\d{3,6}.*)-(OE|NRA)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZtYUvq/1)

Without the anchors you could make the quantifier non greedy and use word boundaries:

```
\b(\d{4})-(ACE|AEA|A[AG]L|AN[EM]|AS[WO]|AWP|WT[EW])-(\d{3,6}.*?)-(OE|NRA)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kSzo85/1)

Comment: ..or `(A(?:AL|CE|EA|GL|N[EM]|S[OW]|WP)|WT[EW])`, which quickly evaluates three-character strings that don't begin with `'A'`.